# How to create a table dynamically?

Tags: java, android, xml, row, tablelayout

I know that it's possible to have an XML file with a TableLayout, and another XML file with a row. And then it's somehow possible to add rows, from the second file, with custom content in the java code to the table in the first file. But I can't find an example that shows how this is done. So, does anyone here know where I can find an example that shows this? I know that I have seen it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Dynamically adding rows to TableLayout](http://en.androidwiki.com/wiki/Dynamically_adding_rows_to_TableLayout)
- [Dynamically add rows to TableLayout](http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/dynamically-add-rows-to-tablelayout-t672.html)

First results using Google. Whatever... the idea is really simple:

1. Get a reference of the `TableLayout` (either one declared in a XML file, or created by hand using `new TableLayou(context)`)
2. For each row you want to add, create a new `TableRow` object. Again, you can do so by using an already defined `TableRow` in an XML and inflate it; or you can just created by using the `new` operator.
3. Add the items you want to put inside each row by using the `addView` method. Sometimes you will want to specify some `TableRow.LayoutParams`.
4. Add the `TableRow` to the `TableLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your `TableLayout`, you can inflate and add rows using:

```
TableRow row = (TableRow) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
    R.layout.table_row, tableLayout, false);
tableLayout.addView(row);
```